# Google AutoML prediction from IntelliJ Idea returns NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I have sucessfully trained my single label text classification model in AutoML. In GCP console I can make predictions on model without problems. But when I try to make prediction from IntelliJ I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom([Ljava/lang/String;[Lcom/google/protobuf/Descriptors$FileDescriptor;)Lcom/google/protobuf/Descriptors$FileDescriptor;
    at com.google.api.HttpProto.<clinit>(HttpProto.java:67)
    at com.google.api.AnnotationsProto.<clinit>(AnnotationsProto.java:69)
    at com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.PredictionServiceProto.<clinit>(PredictionServiceProto.java:132)
    at com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.PredictRequest$ParamsDefaultEntryHolder.<clinit>(PredictRequest.java:268)
    at com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.PredictRequest$Builder.internalGetParams(PredictRequest.java:1148)
    at com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.PredictRequest$Builder.buildPartial(PredictRequest.java:725)
    at com.google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.PredictRequest$Builder.build(PredictRequest.java:707)
    at com.newsProcessor.text.GoogleTextAnalyser.predict(GoogleTextAnalyser.java:37)
```

I have created service account, created JSON key, downloaded the key, created GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to the location of the downloaded key. In my Java code I have set the correct projectId and modelId.

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String projectId = "MY-PROJECT-ID";
        String modelId = "MY-MODEL-ID";
        String content = "The Gulf states accuse Iran of supplying arms to the Houthis a charge Tehran and the group deny";
        predict(projectId, modelId, content);
    }

    static void predict(String projectId, String modelId, String content) throws IOException {
        try (PredictionServiceClient client = PredictionServiceClient.create()) {
            ModelName name = ModelName.of(projectId, "us-central1", modelId);
            TextSnippet textSnippet =
                    TextSnippet.newBuilder()
                            .setContent(content)
                            .setMimeType("text/plain")
                            .build();
            ExamplePayload payload = ExamplePayload.newBuilder().setTextSnippet(textSnippet).build();
            PredictRequest predictRequest =
                    PredictRequest.newBuilder().setName(name.toString()).setPayload(payload).build();

            PredictResponse response = client.predict(predictRequest);

            for (AnnotationPayload annotationPayload : response.getPayloadList()) {
                System.out.format("Predicted class name: %s\n", annotationPayload.getDisplayName());
                System.out.format(
                        "Predicted sentiment score: %.2f\n\n",
                        annotationPayload.getClassification().getScore());
            }
        }
    }
```

Do you have a clue what can be wrong please? Because the error itself does not make a lot of sense to me.

My Maven dependencies are:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>19.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-language</artifactId>
        <version>1.52.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-automl</artifactId>
        <version>0.55.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are your dependencies?

Comment: Hi Guillaueme. I added my dependencies into the question.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this issue without IntelliJ. Have you tried using the IntelliJ plugin to install the libraries? See https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/client-libraries.
Also, you're using a beta version of auto-ml; the BOM automatically controls the versions, so you don't need to specify the beta version within your pom.xml. Try removing that version tag for google-cloud-automl. See the installation process here: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/client-libraries#installing_the_client_library